# How are the Leviathans linked with the Void in the Dishonored series?

Tags: dishonored

[image: Image of a Leviathan in the Void]

I know that Leviathans are an embodiment of sadness and despair, and a perfect subject for the Outsider's attention, but how are they linked to the Void? Why are they just floating about in the Void?

Comment: I don't have an authoritative answer, but it's interesting that their bones are used for charms and almost always found at the site of Outsider shrines. Might suggest some inherent void connection that the beasts have, like perhaps they naturally exist inside and outside the void at the same time.

Comment: I mean yeah that is rather interesting how they use whale bones like I know that they’re not violent creatures and dive deep down into the ocean to escape the mass genocide but what if that’s where the void recides in death of the outsider lurk goes to the void and it is surrounded by shallow water

Answer (score 3):

The original tweet no longer seems to exist, but the [Dishonored wikia](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Whales#comm-64259) includes a [screenshot of a twitter conversation](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/File:Developer_commentary,_whales.png) between DH lead writer Harvey Smith and another user about the nature of [whales](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Whales):

[image: Smith says: "whales exist both materially in the world and spiritually in the Void, simultaneously"]

So, whales seem to be dual-natured, and have both a physical embodiment in the world and a spiritual embodiment in the Void at the same time. That'd explain why we see so many leviathans floating about on the protagonists' trips to the Void, and why artefacts made from whales can act as a sort of conduit for the Void.

Comment: Harvey Smith deleted all his tweets just to be annoying (probably had a better reason but it IS annoying)